# ng-model de um objeto

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho uma controller:

```
function ItemsCrtl($scope) {

      $scope.items = [
        {id: 0, name: "PC"},
        {id: 2, name: "GEladeira"},
        {id: 3, name: "Fogao"},
        {id: 4, name: "cama"},
        {id: 5, name: "privada"},
        {id: 6, name: "sofá"}
      ]

    }
```

E no meu html:

```
<div ng-controller="ItemsCrtl">    
<input type="text" ng-model="items.name">
     <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
       {{item.id}} - {{item.name}}
      </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Porém o ng-model não funciona, ele não filtra a lista pelo nome do item.
Como fazer nesse caso quando é uma lista de objetos.

Comment: E o controller?

Comment: Não mudou muita coisa, mas tá aí o controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu imagino que seu problema esteja em outro ponto, durante o processo de inicialização da sua aplicação.

O exemplo funcional abaixo declara a função utilizando a extensão `.controller()`. Clique em <kbd>Executar</kbd> para vê-lo funcionando.

o valor a ser pesquisado é armazenado em `$filtro`. Este valor é então utilizado no `ng-repeat`, specificando que este valor deve ser comparando com o conteúdo da propriedade `name` de cada objeto da coleção.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('ItemsCrtl', function($scope){
   $scope.items = [
        {id: 0, name: "PC"},
        {id: 2, name: "GEladeira"},
        {id: 3, name: "Fogao"},
        {id: 4, name: "cama"},
        {id: 5, name: "privada"},
        {id: 6, name: "sofá"}
      ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ItemsCrtl">    
     <input type="text" ng-model="$filtro">
     <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {name: $filtro}">
       {{item.id}} - {{item.name}}
      </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mas e a parte para exibir na lista somente items que correspondem a palavra digitada? <input type="text" ng-model="items.name">

Comment: @FelipeCoelho Eu copiei o passo errado do exemplo, obrigado por apontar meu erro! Eu atualizei com a resposta correta.

Comment: Funcionou!! Excelente obrigado!!